# Create new bash var from value of dict bash var

Tags: bash, dictionary, indexing, awk, environment-variables

My environment created a variable that looks like this:

```
SM_TRAINING_ENV={"additional_framework_parameters":{},"channel_input_dirs":{"training":"/opt/ml/input/data/training"},"current_host":"algo-1","framework_module":"sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training:main","hosts":["algo-1"],"hyperparameters":{"bool_param":true,"float_param":1.25,"int_param":5,"model_dir":"s3://bucket/detection/prefix/testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194/model","str_param":"bla"},"input_config_dir":"/opt/ml/input/config","input_data_config":{"training":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}},"input_dir":"/opt/ml/input","is_master":true,"job_name":"testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194","log_level":20,"master_hostname":"algo-1","model_dir":"/opt/ml/model","module_dir":"s3://bucket/prefix/testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194/source/sourcedir.tar.gz","module_name":"launcher.sh","network_interface_name":"ethwe","num_cpus":8,"num_gpus":1,"output_data_dir":"/opt/ml/output/data","output_dir":"/opt/ml/output","output_intermediate_dir":"/opt/ml/output/intermediate","resource_config":{"current_host":"algo-1","hosts":["algo-1"],"network_interface_name":"ethwe"},"user_entry_point":"launcher.sh"}
```

**EDIT** by Ed Morton: per [the OPs comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551587/create-new-bash-var-from-value-of-dict-bash-var?noredirect=1#comment97821820_55551587), this is what (s)he is trying to describe above as the sample input:

```
$ SM_TRAINING_ENV='{"additional_framework_parameters":{},"channel_input_dirs":{"training":"/opt/ml/input/data/training"},"current_host":"algo-1","framework_module":"sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training:main","hosts":["algo-1"],"hyperparameters":{"bool_param":true,"float_param":1.25,"int_param":5,"model_dir":"s3://bucket/detection/prefix/testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194/model","str_param":"bla"},"input_config_dir":"/opt/ml/input/config","input_data_config":{"training":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}},"input_dir":"/opt/ml/input","is_master":true,"job_name":"testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194","log_level":20,"master_hostname":"algo-1","model_dir":"/opt/ml/model","module_dir":"s3://bucket/prefix/testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194/source/sourcedir.tar.gz","module_name":"launcher.sh","network_interface_name":"ethwe","num_cpus":8,"num_gpus":1,"output_data_dir":"/opt/ml/output/data","output_dir":"/opt/ml/output","output_intermediate_dir":"/opt/ml/output/intermediate","resource_config":{"current_host":"algo-1","hosts":["algo-1"],"network_interface_name":"ethwe"},"user_entry_point":"launcher.sh"}'

$ echo "$SM_TRAINING_ENV"
{"additional_framework_parameters":{},"channel_input_dirs":{"training":"/opt/ml/input/data/training"},"current_host":"algo-1","framework_module":"sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training:main","hosts":["algo-1"],"hyperparameters":{"bool_param":true,"float_param":1.25,"int_param":5,"model_dir":"s3://bucket/detection/prefix/testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194/model","str_param":"bla"},"input_config_dir":"/opt/ml/input/config","input_data_config":{"training":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}},"input_dir":"/opt/ml/input","is_master":true,"job_name":"testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194","log_level":20,"master_hostname":"algo-1","model_dir":"/opt/ml/model","module_dir":"s3://bucket/prefix/testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194/source/sourcedir.tar.gz","module_name":"launcher.sh","network_interface_name":"ethwe","num_cpus":8,"num_gpus":1,"output_data_dir":"/opt/ml/output/data","output_dir":"/opt/ml/output","output_intermediate_dir":"/opt/ml/output/intermediate","resource_config":{"current_host":"algo-1","hosts":["algo-1"],"network_interface_name":"ethwe"},"user_entry_point":"launcher.sh"}
```

How can I create a new bash variable that is equal to the value of `SM_TRAINING_ENV["hyperparameters"]["model_dir"]`?

For completeness, I was trying simple things like `echo ${SM_TRAINING_ENV} | jq .` and kept getting errors with everything I tried.

**Edit:** I've been informed that this value isn't a proper json, so rewording the question. I think the environment sets it to the value of a python dictionary, so `jq` seems not usable. Removed `json` tag. Maybe this is a job for `awk`?

It looks like I can match the value I want if I assume the structure doesn't change with the regex pattern `s3.*?model`, but not sure how to set a regex pattern to a new variable.

Comment: What did you search for before asking here? [`man jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

Comment: I've been trying jq and regex, couldn't figure out how to use it properly. Kept getting the error `jq: error: additional_framework_parameters/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:`

Comment: You should still show what you tried, to make the question complete.

Comment: Edited with that info

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `a variable that looks like this` as the text that follows that statement doesn't look like a variable. Are you trying to say you have a variable (named `var`, say) which if you do `echo "$var"` outputs `SM_TRAINING_ENV={"add...sh"}` or that you have a variable named `SM_TRAINING_ENV` which if you do `echo "$SM_TRAINING_ENV"` outputs `{"add...sh"}` or something else?

Comment: what is the output of `echo $SM_TRAINING_ENV` ?

Comment: @EdMorton the latter

Comment: @Austin Please add the output of `echo "$SM_TRAINING_ENV"` to the question, so we can see for ourselves exactly what it contains.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This doesn't really index but it works if order is always the same:

`NEW_VAR=$(echo $SM_TRAINING_ENV | egrep -o s3.*?model | head -1)`

Would much prefer something not dependent on order though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to quote the JSON value so that the double quotes will be included in the value.

```
SM_TRAINING_ENV='{"additional_framework_parameters":{},"channel_input_dirs":{"training":"/opt/ml/input/data/training"},"current_host":"algo-1","framework_module":"sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training:main","hosts":["algo-1"],"hyperparameters":{"bool_param":true,"float_param":1.25,"int_param":5,"model_dir":"s3://bucket/detection/prefix/testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194/model","str_param":"bla"},"input_config_dir":"/opt/ml/input/config","input_data_config":{"training":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}},"input_dir":"/opt/ml/input","is_master":true,"job_name":"testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194","log_level":20,"master_hostname":"algo-1","model_dir":"/opt/ml/model","module_dir":"s3://bucket/prefix/testing-2019-04-06-02-24-20-194/source/sourcedir.tar.gz","module_name":"launcher.sh","network_interface_name":"ethwe","num_cpus":8,"num_gpus":1,"output_data_dir":"/opt/ml/output/data","output_dir":"/opt/ml/output","output_intermediate_dir":"/opt/ml/output/intermediate","resource_config":{"current_host":"algo-1","hosts":["algo-1"],"network_interface_name":"ethwe"},"user_entry_point":"launcher.sh"}'
```

Then you can use the `jq` utility to extract the value you want.

```
new_var=$(echo "$SM_TRAINING_ENV" | jq '.hyperparameters.model_dir')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, how can I create a new var by wrapping quotes around the original?

Comment: You don't need to create a new var, you just have to do it when assigning to the variable as I showed.

Comment: If you're not setting the variable using a literal string assignment, it's not an issue. This is just for literals, not assigning from other sources.

Comment: I haven't assigned the variable it was created by my environment and I don't know the values a priori.

Comment: Do you see the double quotes if you do `echo "$SM_TRAINING_ENV"`. Then they're doing it correctly. If they didn't do it correctly, there's no way to fix it, since the information is lost.

Comment: No I don't see double quotes around the entire var when I do that. I find it hard to believe there's no way to parse this variable though..

Comment: Not around the entire var, I mean around the strings inside it, like `additional_framework_parameters`

Comment: Oh sorry, no there's no double quotes around those either.

Comment: Then the code that assigns the variable needs to be fixed like I showed.

Comment: You can't fix it in your code, it has to be fixed there.

Comment: They're creating invalid JSON.

Comment: Can I use something besides `jq` then? I guess `SM_TRAINING_ENV` value is really a python dictionary instead of a proper json.

Comment: It might be possible to treat the value as a `jq` filter to output valid JSON: `jq  -n "$SM_TRAINING_ENV"`.

Comment: @Austin Python dictionaries also require strings to be quoted.

Comment: @Austin wrt [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551587/create-new-bash-var-from-value-of-dict-bash-var?noredirect=1#comment97804826_55551670) about strings like `additional_framework_parameters` that `there's no double quotes around those either.` - your posted sample input `SM_TRAINING_ENV={"additional_framework_parameters":...` specifically SHOWS double quotes around that specific string so what do you mean by that statement? Is your comment wrong or is your posted sample input wrong?

Comment: @EdMorton I have single quotes around the string in the assignment, so the double quotes are retained. In his assignment, there are no quotes around the whole thing, so the shell will remove the double quotes after using them to quote the strings.

Comment: @Barmar in the comments under her question I asked if `echo "$SM_TRAINING_ENV"` outputs `{"add...sh"}` (i.e. with quotes) and she said that it does. She apparently isn't populating the variable herself, some tool is doing it, so then how can she post the contents of the variable showing double quotes if they aren't present? I don't think she just invented/typed that long string by hand. I would say she's definitely wrong when she told you there aren't quotes present except that then your `jq` would work so idk what's really happening. She never said in what way your command fails.

Comment: @EdMorton They said how it failed in a comment to a similar answer that's been deleted: **parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 33** I think you have enough rep to see deleted answers. But neither of us gets that error if we use the properly quoted JSON literal.

Comment: idk, whatever is going on it's clear that what's in the question is not a [mcve]!

Comment: Since part of the actual problem involves an external application that they don't have access to, it seems like they may have trouble creating that.

Comment: If they have an application that's generating a variable `var` populated with `foo "bar"'` or `foo bar`, it'd be easy for them to do `echo "$var"` or similar to see `var`s contents after that application runs and then create a MCVE with `var='foo "bar"'` or `var='foo bar'` as the starting point instead.